# How to create a makefile prerequisite from the target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using GNU make, and I'm trying to create the prerequisites based on target. I want the prerequisite to be the basename of the target. So, when I run this:

```
make a/b/foo.txt
```

it should run this:

```
cp foo.txt a/b/foo.txt
```

None of these work:

```
a/%.txt: $(basename $@)
    cp $< $@

a/%.txt: $(@F)
    cp $< $@

a/%.txt: $(shell basename $@)
    cp $< $@

a/%.txt: $(basename %)
    cp $< $@

a/%.txt: $(shell basename %)
    cp $< $@
```

I've seen % used in targets and prerequisites, so I know it's normal to base the prerequisites on the targets. I've also seen variables in the prerequisites, so this is also normal. But it seems the special variables $@ and $(@F) are unavailable in the prerequisites, as well as functions like basename and shell. Is there some way I can work around this limitation?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `a/b/%.txt: %.txt`?

Comment: The idea here is that the directory a is known. The rest can be anything: a/b/c/d/foo.txt, a/c/d/foo.txt, etc. It should copy foo.txt to the target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$(shell)` versions are wrong as they confuse execution timing.

The `$(shell)` command itself is processed at make parse-time but the value of 
`$@` only exists at target execution time.

The same holds true for the `$(basename)` expansions.

What you can use here, though, is [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

a/%.txt: $$(notdir $$@)
        @echo '$$@: $@'
        @echo '$$<: $<'
```